# Retrieve <value> of promise from input file

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have an HTML file with the following code:

```
<input type="File" id="myFile" name="filename" onchange="loadFile(this.files[0])">
```

And a javascript file with the following code:

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('myFile');
    fileInput.onchange = () => {
      var allFolders = fileInput.files[0].text();
      console.log(allFolders);
    }
```

When I open my console log, I receive the message:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
​
<state>: "fulfilled"
​
<value>: "{'1' : { '2' : { '3' : { 'a': {}, 'b' : {}, 'c' : {}}}}};"
```

I want to console log **ONLY** the value so that my console log returns

```
"{'1' : { '2' : { '3' : { 'a': {}, 'b' : {}, 'c' : {}}}}};"
```

but I am not sure how to retrieve it, given the structure of the code I have written. Does anyone know, using the simple code I already have functioning, what to add to make console.log(allFolders) return the value of the promise?

Comment: Use `await` or `.then()`

Answer (score -1):

> `fileInput.files[0].text();`

this returns a [`Promise<string>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text).
To get the value of a Promise, you need to `await` it, so prepend `await`.
In order to use await, the function needs to be async, so you need to add the async keyword before the function parameters.
It should end up looking like:

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById('myFile');
fileInput.onchange = async () => {
  var allFolders = await fileInput.files[0].text();
  console.log(allFolders);
}
```

Comment: thank you! This seems to have achieved what I was looking for!